# Locating Robert Bruce Moore who was born 1893 in Texas and disappeared in about 1917?

Tags: united-states, world-war-1, texas, 1910s

Robert Bruce Moore:

- was born in Oct 1893 in Texas, USA
- was recorded in [1900 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M3RM-WSG) in Justice Precinct 1, Young County, Texas, USA as being born Oct 1893 in Texas
- was recorded in [1910 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M29P-P53) in Justice Precinct 4, Briscoe County, USA as being born about 1894 in Texas
- son, Robert Benjamin Moore, born in 1914 in Fresno, California
- appears to have disappeared in about 1917

Our family legends say 3 possible things happened to him:

- He was shot gun forced to marry my great grandmother because he got her pregnant with my grandfather. He was being forced by his father Benjamin Marion Moore. His siblings believed this one the most.
- His brother said that he ran off to Canada or French foreign legion to join the war because he really wanted to.
- He may havedraft dodged.

Regardless, he seemed to have fallen off the face of the earth.

However, it is possible that he may have contacted the family twice:

- There was a rumor of a letter in the 1920s
- There was a rumor that he stopped by in the 1930s and left before his mother could get there.

Can someone please help with locating anything about my missing grandfather?

I've already ruled out so many, and the name is so common.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn how our focussed Q&A works because it is different to a bulletin board, discussion forum and other Q&A sites.  As your question stands I think it is too broad because it is asking many questions e.g. did he join the French Foreign Legion? did he draft dodge? did he avoid marriage?  I think the first of these seems like one the most answerable, but I think you can also improve your question by giving us the details of those 1900 and 1910 census records because they seem to be the last you know of him with some certainty.

Comment: I think it is essential to look at case studies from other genealogists who have researched people who "just disappeared" -- so I recommend that you take the webinar coming up on Saturday, December 5 "The Curious Case of the Disappearing Dude" which is being presented by the Southern California Genealogical Society,  If you attend the live broadcast you can watch it for free -- afterwards, the recording is available only to members of the Society. See the schedule at http://www.scgsgenealogy.com/webinar/jes-index.html  I agree that your question as written is much too vague and too broad.

Comment: http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=7602&h=44651432&ssrc=pt&tid=64148540&pid=30458687399&usePUB=true

Comment: http://interactive.ancestry.com/7884/4449976_01238/136639471?backurl=http://person.ancestry.com/tree/64148540/person/30458687399/facts/citation/163082441440/edit/record

Comment: This site doesn't cooperate with my cell very well. Above links are the only two facts I found of him. No one in my family direct line has found anything on him. My Aunt has been looking for over 30 years. Joy, his son's second wife, thought he died in france.

Comment: This is the last picture we have of him in our family bible.

Comment: http://mv.ancestry.com/viewer/84f133a2-3444-4f70-9d81-088e25be0e0c/64148540/30458687399?_phsrc=aMW128&_phstart=default&usePUBJs=true

Comment: Who was the rumoured letter written to?  Have you tried to see if anyone still has it?  If not, is there any rumour as to what its contents were?

Comment: It was written to a brother, but the letter is long gone and so are his siblings. We only have his brother's children to confer with. They are in Tucumcari NM.

Comment: Utilmately, there are thousands of unidentified ww1 soldiers spread out throughout Europe, and only God knows.